# ¿Porque la clase MediaPlayer solo me reproduce algunas canciones?

Tags: java, android-studio

Tengo un reproductor de música donde hay alojadas canciones de extensión mp3 en la carpeta raw. Pero al momento de ejecutar la aplicación solo me reproduce algunas.
 También al presionar siguiente varias veces solo me reproduce algunas canciones y me dejan de reproducir de repente.

Les dejo mi código para ayudarme a encontar el problema.

```
Button play_pause, 
btn_repetir;
MediaPlayer mp;
ImageView iv;
int repetir = 2, posicion = 0;

MediaPlayer vectormp [] = new MediaPlayer [3];

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_album1);

    play_pause = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_play);
    btn_repetir = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_repetir);
    iv = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);

    vectormp[0] = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.uno_magia);
    vectormp[1] = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.dos_pasarla_bien);
    vectormp[2] = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.tres_me_gusta_todo_de_ti);
}
```

Este método es para el botón playpause

```
public void PlayPause(View view){
    if(vectormp[posicion].isPlaying()){
        vectormp[posicion].pause();
        play_pause.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.reproducir);
        Toast.makeText(this, "Pausa", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {
        vectormp[posicion].start();
        play_pause.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.pausa);
        Toast.makeText(this, "Play", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}}
```

Método para saltar a la siguiente canción.

```
public void Siguiente(View view){
    if(posicion < vectormp.length -1){

        if(vectormp[posicion].isPlaying()){
            vectormp[posicion].stop();
            posicion++;
            vectormp[posicion].start();

            if(posicion == 0){
                iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.portada1);
            } else if(posicion == 1){
                iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.portada2);
            }else if(posicion == 2){
                iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.portada3); 
         }

        } else {
            posicion++;

            if(posicion == 0){
                iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.portada1);
            } else if(posicion == 1){
                iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.portada2);
            }else if(posicion == 2){
                iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.portada3);
    }}
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "No hay más canciones", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Método para retroceder a la anterior canción

```
    public void Anterior(View view){
    if(posicion >= 1){

        if(vectormp[posicion].isPlaying()){
            vectormp[posicion].stop();
            vectormp[0] = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.uno_magia);
            vectormp[1] = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.dos_pasarla);
            vectormp[2] = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.tres_me_gusta);
            posicion--;       
    }
```